# show specific content for each registered user in joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am looking for a module/extension, or something that can help me to 
make a page/item that only one specific user registered can see.
I would like also create a space dedicated to this user, where i can publish there pages and aticles.

Maybe using php and the variable that contains the username and an iframe, but I dont know how to doit.

Thank for the help

Answer (score 0):

[GMAccess](http://www.eduvs.ch/gmaccess/) is a Joomla! component that makes managing groups and access permissions easy, you will be able to create a special group and add your user (via Joomla's user management) to it and manage which pages can be viewed by that group.

Comment: Aquiles has written "...joomla 1.6" in the headline. With the little French I know, it seems that GMAccess is only available for Joomla 1.5. Besides, what you describe here, should be part of Joomla 1.6 without any extra component.